# Graphite max of a series with wildcards

Tags: aggregate, series, graphite

I'm looking for something similar to sumSeriesWithWildcards, but for max/min. I mean, instead calculating the sum aggregated on the desired fields, it should calculate min or max. I was surprised not to find a maxSeriesWithWildcards call in Graphite library.
In case it doesn't exist, how could I simulate that ?

Thanks,
Greetings,
   Sorin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`groupByNode`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode). It takes list of metrics that you want to group by the given node with the specified function - any function can be used.

For example:

```
test.region-1.server-1
test.region-1.server-2
test.region-1.server-3
test.region-1.server-4
test.region-1.server-5

test.region-2.server-1
test.region-2.server-2
test.region-2.server-3
test.region-2.server-4
test.region-2.server-5

test.region-3.server-1
test.region-3.server-2
test.region-3.server-3
test.region-3.server-4
test.region-3.server-5
```

to get sums per region you would use:

```
sumSeriesWithWildcards(test.*.*, 2)
```

the same you can do with groupByNode*:

```
groupByNode(test.*.*, 1, 'sumSeries')
```

**Note** the node number in `sumSeriesWithWildcards` is the one you want to sum, but in the `groupByNode` you must specify the node you want to group by. Also the labels will be shorter in the groupByNode - only the grouping node.

So... to the point:

- min: `groupByNode(test.*.*, 1, 'minSeries')`
- max: `groupByNode(test.*.*, 1, 'maxSeries')`
- avg: `groupByNode(test.*.*, 1, 'averageSeries')`

There is also [`groupByNodes`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNodes), you can provide more nodes as significant.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was experimenting indeed with groupByNode. One issue though is that the results remove part of the query, i.e. in your example above, you'll get all fields removed, except for number 1 (the "region-X", on which you aggregate). So you'll have to reconstruct the original query if you need that.
Thanks,

Comment: just use groupsByNodes with as many nodes as you want to keep e.g. `groupByNodes(test.*.*,  'minSeries', 0,1)`

Comment: I can't find groupByNodes in the documentation: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.10/functions.html; where have you got that from ?

Comment: http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNodes it is in the latest release, but this is fairly old (2yrs ago) https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blame/1.0.x/webapp/graphite/render/functions.py#L3570

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why nobody suggested [maxSeries](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.maxSeries) function that does take a wildcard series list.

Comment: funny enough, at the time of the writing there was no maxSeries function yet